# Performance issue with postgresql query involving UPDATE SET FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, query-performance

We're experiencing performance issues with a postgresql query similar to the following

```
UPDATE table_A
SET table_A.column_X = 'some_constant'
FROM table_B 
WHERE table_B.table_A_id = table_A.id
AND table_A.column_Y = 'some_other_constant' 
AND table_B.column_Z = 'some_third_constant'
AND table_A.column_X IS NULL
```

There is an index on `table_A (column_Y)` which should in theory restrict the number of rows in `table_A` that need considering to something very small. I am not familiar with the `UPDATE SET FROM WHERE` combination. Could this be repeatedly doing a full scan of `table_B` for every match in `table_A`? Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with this query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  (Note that running `explain (analyze)` will actually **run** the statement, not just explain it. So the rows will be updated)

Comment: `WHERE table_B.table_A_id = table_A.id` :: This *could* be a FK->PK relation. Or it could *not*

Comment: @joop Sorry it is a FK relation. I'm working on improving the question.

Comment: I mean it is a FK -> PK relation